# Export a concrete version of a generic TypeScript class

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

For a module written in TS but consumed in both JS and TS, I have a utility class which (at the point it's defined) is generic with some constraint:

```js
// util/genericthing.ts

interface TOwnerBase {
  someExpectedMethod: { (param: number): void };
}

export class GenericThing<TOwner extends TOwnerBase> {
  owner: TOwner;

  constructor(owner: TOwner) {
    this.owner = owner;
    owner.someExpectedMethod(0);
  }
}
```

Later, the user-facing owning class is defined with reference to this generic (works around what would otherwise be a circular dependency here):

```js
// main.ts

import { GenericThing } from "./util/genericthing";

export class ThingOwner {
  things: GenericThing<ThingOwner>[];

  someExpectedMethod(param: number) {};
}

export { GenericThing } from "./util/genericthing";
```

But in expected usage of the module/library, users *shouldn't need to care* about this generic: `TOwner` will always be `ThingOwner`.

This is clunky because users (who would typically just import from `main.ts`) will need to import and use the pair `GenericThing<ThingOwner>` if referencing the type. Instead, I'd like them to just reference something like `Thing` which implicitly resolves the generic.

A type alias like `export type Thing = GenericThing<ThingOwner>;` doesn't seem to be a good fit, because it can only be used as a type and not a concrete implementation:

```js
// User code
import { Thing, ThingOwner } from "my-cool-module";

// This is fine - because Thing is a type:
let myThing: Thing;

// This is not - because Thing is not a constructor/class:
myThing = new Thing(new ThingOwner());
```

How could `main.ts` export a concrete version of `Thing` that's usable as both a type and an actual class? Or is there some different pattern that should be used here instead?

Comment: The easiest thing to do is to make `Thing` a subclass of `GenericThing`, like `class Thing extends GenericThing<ThingOwner> {}`.  Otherwise you need to define `Thing` as both a type and a value; in TS4.7 you can use instantiation expressions to write `const Thing: typeof GenericThing<ThingOwner> = GenericThing;`, in TS4.6 and below you need to write out the type manually.  Both solutions are shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/N5e22N).  Does that address your question? If so I can write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Thanks @jcalz, yes that makes sense - I wonder if there's any significant runtime or usage/hinting difference between simply extending the class and the other option which I'd characterize as just aliasing types/constants? It seems like the TS4.7+ solution might be more direct than the TS4.6 or extends solutions which both seem to introduce an explicit extra layer.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow the following works in TypeScript 4.6.3 :

```
//specificthing.ts
import { GenericThing } from "./genericthing";

export class ThingOwner {
  things!: GenericThing<ThingOwner>[]; 
  someExpectedMethod(param: number) {}; 
}

export { GenericThing } from "./genericthing";

export const Thing = GenericThing;
export type Thing = GenericThing<ThingOwner>;
```

(Yes, two different exports with the same name `Thing`: one value and one type).
And it can be used like

```
import { Thing, ThingOwner } from "./specificthing";

let myThing: Thing = new Thing(new ThingOwner());
```

---

Edit: However, `Thing` will still be detected as having a type parameter, for example a user can see `(alias) new Thing<ThingOwner>(owner: ThingOwner): GenericThing<ThingOwner>` in VSCode.

To prevent the user from seeing that, I changed the exports to:

```
export const Thing: new (owner: ThingOwner) => Thing = GenericThing;
export type Thing = GenericThing<ThingOwner>;
```

Then it's shown as `(alias) new Thing(owner: ThingOwner): Thing`